# DNS server is not responding

Tags: windows-7, networking, dns, internet, lenovo-laptop

For the last week my Windows 7 laptop has been unable to connect to the Internet. When I tried to troubleshoot the issue I received the following warning:

> DNS server is not responding

However the Internet connection does exist. As the data transfer rate is changing, I have the yellow triangle most of the time. I also tried restoring the computer to all the previous dates but the problem still exists.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: What are the values in your IP configuration?

Comment: 192.168.0.109
255.255.255.0
--------------------
Preferred DNS serve:213.131.66.138
alternate DNS server:213.131.66.139

Comment: DNS and your internet connection are very different things. Without DNS you still can access the internet, you just can't resolve web pages. The yellow triangle you describe is an issue on your local network, and probably isn't related to DNS, but something with your IP assignment. Is your addressing DHCP or static? How is your network set up? are you going through a router before going into a modem? If so is the modem PPPOE or is it bridged? If so do you get the same problem when not using your router? Can you ping your default gateway?

Answer (score 4):

The message "`DNS server is not responding`" already explains it: Both the DNS servers that you have configured are unreachable for some reason.

Try changing your DNS servers – for example, to

- [Google Public DNS](http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/) (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4),
- Level3 (4.2.2.4, 4.2.2.3, 4.2.2.2)
- [OpenDNS](https://store.opendns.com/setup/operatingsystem/windows-7) (208.67.220.220 and 208.67.222.222)

Answer (score 2):

Your ip address is from a local network. That means you can still access your local area network but it does not mean an internet connection exists.

The first thing I notice when my internet connection is down is Windows 7 telling me it couldn't connect to the DNS servers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes sometimes I have this problem,I type in ip into the search bar and when it comes up I go to disable this network and then to enable this network,it works for me.